# Newbie Question About Basic Selecting

Tags: selection-tools

I've got a very basic model, which is just two shapes at the moment.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to select the bottom shape.  Clicking on it only moves the 3D cursor around, but doesn't change the selection.  All the tutorials I've seen have to do with selecting a specific vertex or face of a shape that's already selected.  I'm lost on how to select a completely different shape in the model.

[image]

Comment: Selection in Blender is, by default with the right-mouse button, not left. You also seem to be in *Edit Mode* in your cube, forbidding selection of other objects. Press `Tab`to enter/exit *Edit Mode*.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  So simple, yet so hard to find.  Thanks, that fixed everything.